# View that covers viewController including navigation bar, but when I add subview it disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```html
        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate)
        let backgrView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
        backgrView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        backgrView.alpha = 0.6
        appDelegate.window!.addSubview(backgrView)
```

the code above allows me to make a view that covers the entire screen even the navigation controller

but when I add the code below `backgrView` disappears:

```
let sampleview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0))
        sampleview.addSubview(backgrView)
```

how can I add a view to the `backgrView`??

Comment: I'd suggest using the [View Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2) and see if your `backgrView` is there, and if so, whether it has some strange `frame` value, blocked by another view, or whatever. If you temporarily give this view a unique `tag` numeric value (or some custom `UIView` subclass), that will help you identify it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sampleview is not added even to view hierarchy so you can add to it backgrView.
Try this instead:

```
    let sampleview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0))
    backgrView.addSubview(sampleview)
```

Or this:

```
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate)
    let backgrView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
    backgrView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    backgrView.alpha = 0.6
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(backgrView)
    let sampleview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0))
    backgrView.addSubview(sampleview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is backwards:

```
    sampleview.addSubview(backgrView)
```

You mean:

```
    backgrView.addSubview(sampleview)
```